# SSD Scratch Disk

Tags: hardware, system

Can Blender make use of a scratch disc?

Use of a separate SSD as scratch disc in photoshop is new information to me.
Can Blender also make use of such a setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solid answer depends on what you specifically mean by "scratch disk".

If you mean using an SSD for some of the stuff that would normally be kept in a memory cache and discarded when the cache limit is reached, I'm not sure.

If you mean "Can I move my Blender temporary folders to an SSD", then yes.

Just go to `File > User Preferences > File` and set new paths on the SSD for things like "Temp" and "Render Output".

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Yes I mean stuff that would normally be kept in a memory cache. On the latter, would I notice any performance increase by changing the temp and render output paths to a seperate SSD?

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to look up a way to do that. However, if you haven't already, check whether you have room to increase the `Memory Cache Limit` setting under `File > User Preferences > System > Sequencer / Clip Editor`. I'm not sure how the default for that is calculated and it could be too conservative.

Answer (score 0):

The tech's do not know what Scratch Disk means. To cache all the information on external drives. Photoshop has this option that allows users to work faster when rendering out their effects. Blender does not have that easy click option. But I found this on Google that has help me out on my renders.

How do I change the scratch disk in Blender?

Just go to File > User Preferences > File and set new paths on the SSD for things like "Temporary Files", Render Cache", and "Render Output". Place sub-folders and link to them. That should help.